# How to sort pushed array by id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two arrays. First one which comes from response is divided by pagination. When i remove items from second array, they should be placed back sorted by id in first array, instead they go to bottom of array and i have to scroll down to find certain element. **This is my code for pushing elements from array vm.feeds to vm.rationList**:

```
function addAll() {
        var mList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.feeds))
        for (var i = 0; i < mList.length; i++) {
            mList[i].is_selected = false;
            vm.rationList.push(mList[i]);
        }
        vm.feeds = [];
        vm.rationListSafe = vm.rationList;
            if(vm.feeds.length == 0){
                vm.currentPageMaster++;
                vm.isPage = true;
                vm.disableScroll = true;
                getFeedsByTeam(vm.selectedTeam);
        }

    }
```

Second part is how i remove elements from array vm.rationList and push them back to first array - vm.feeds:

```
function removeAll() {  
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.rationList.length; i++) {
        vm.feeds.push(vm.rationList[i])
            }
        vm.rationList = []
        }
```

In removeAll() i have to add additional check which will sort them by ID on push. Any idea for this?

Comment: can you please post an example of the array you play with?

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted by id" ? Items in rationList have an id attribute ?

Comment: Yes, each item has ID

Comment: mList: Array(30)
0: {id: 1, ration_feed_id: null, ration_feed_mix_id: null, amount_mix: null, amount_dm: null, …}
1: {id: 2, ration_feed_id: null, ration_feed_mix_id: null, amount_mix: null, amount_dm: null, …}
2: {id: 3, ration_feed_id: null, ration_feed_mix_id: null, amount_mix: null, amount_dm: null, …}
3: {id: 4, ration_feed_id: null, ration_feed_mix_id: null, amount_mix: null, amount_dm: null, …}....

Answer (score 0):

The [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/push) method add item to the end of your list.

To put an element at a given position in an array, you may prefer using [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
First argument is the index, second is the number of items to delete (in your case, 0), and a third argument would be the item to add at the given index.

With that, you can replace the push in removeAll by

```
vm.feeds.splice(correctIndex, 0, vm.rationList[i]);
```

Question is : what is correctIndex ?

Well, for that, there might be many solutions depending on your architecture, but a simple one could be to loop on vm.feeds to find the first item with an id that is not lower than the one you want to add:

```
var correctIndex = 0;
for(var item of vm.feeds) {
    if (item.id >= vm.rationList[i].id) {break;}
    else {correctIndex++;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.feeds.sort(function(a, b) {
            return parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id);
        });
```

This is the solution I found and it works